# Push element in array in last php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I want to push this value(**blue**) in array at last position right now this value is coming outside the array See below output

```
$data = array();
foreach ($labors as $result) {
        $data[] = (array)$result;  
         array_push($data,"blue");

}
```

Output

```
 0 => array:9 [▼
"Date" => "2016-09-04"
"Emp" => "ADDISA01"
"Job" => "24-1604"
"Extra" => null
"Cost" => "26-01-10"
"Union" => null
"Cert" => ""
"Shift" => "1"
"EPay" => "1"
]
"blue" => "1"
```

expected output

```
 0 => array:9 [▼
"Date" => "2016-09-04"
"Emp" => "ADDISA01"
"Job" => "24-1604"
"Extra" => null
"Cost" => "26-01-10"
"Union" => null
"Cert" => ""
"Shift" => "1"
"EPay" => "1"
"blue" => "1"
]
```

Comment: i am astonished that when you `push` how `"blue"` becomes index?  `$data["blue"]=1;` needed instead of `push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try,

```
$data = array();
foreach ($labors as $result) {
    $temp = (array)$result;  
    $temp['blue'] = 1;
    $data[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: But in the question you put that the blue should be string "1" so how can this work fine?

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($labors as $result) {
        $item = (array)$result;  
        $item['blue'] = '1';
        $data[] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($labors as $result) {
    $data1 = (array)$result;  
    $data1['blue'] = 1;
    $data[] = $data1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($labors as $result) {
    $result = (array) $result;
    $result['blue'] = 1;
    $data[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: It will fail if result is an object, i guess that's why there is typecasting